# Invoke a Java class and get a return value in WSO2 BPS 3.2.0

Tags: wso2, bpel

I know that it's possible to invoke a JAVA class within a BPEL process in WSO2 BPS 3.2.0. Sources and tutorial can be found here: 
http://hasithaa.github.io/java4bpel/

My question is: Is it possible not to only invoke a JAVA class but also get a return value from invoked class/method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible. There are two ways of achieving it.

1) By writing a custom xpath function. Refer this for more details. ( I think you are looking for this one) http://ode.apache.org/custom-xpath-functions.html

2) By writing a extension similar to Java4bpel. But you have to set your output to a variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
1) I followed instructions in link - created jar with class Random in package com.example.xpath.Random, copied it to repository/components directory and I created process with assign activity as in example. But I'm getting error: `net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named {java:com.example.xpath.Random}random(). Note that direct calls to Java methods are not available under Saxon-HE.` 
WSO2 bps 3.2.0 uses saxon.he_9.4.0.wso2v1.jar
2) Can you describe how can I set output of extensionActivity to a variable?

Comment: 1) Problem was caused by using Saxon-HE and not Saxon professional or enterprise edition. How to replace Saxon is well described here: http://nandikajayawardana.blogspot.cz/2012/12/how-to-replace-saxonhe940wso2v1jar-in.html 
But this is not good solution to my project, because I'm using only open source/free libs.
2) I still don't know how to set output of extensionActivity to a variable.

Comment: 2) I got it. It's not about setting output of extensionActivity to a variable, but about setting variable value inside java class. `if(variable.equals("tmpVar"))
                        {
                         log.info("Setting value");
                         node.setTextContent("dummy value");                        
                         data.writeVariable(variable, node);
                         log.info("Logging Variable " + variable + " = " + DOMUtils.domToString(node));
                        }`